# Fix error executing updater binary in zip open_gapps-x86-6.0

Tags: rom-flashing, google-apps

I am getting an error while flashing gapps to my OnePlus One running CM 13.
My seLinux is set to permissive and my recovery is TWRP 3.0.0.

Comment: The provided details are not enough, OP. Which package did you flash? From where did you get it? Which error has been thrown?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot flash an x86 build on an ARM device.  Get the ARM version, available at http://opengapps.org/